# How do I use IES lighting with a sphere?

Tags: mesh, light

( Hey,everyone! I'm in a bit of a pickle. I created a wonderful IES node setup thanks to an amazing tutorial and it works with planes and circles. However,I'm having trouble with one mesh in particular,the sphere. When I use a sphere to try and light my scene,its curvature the light scatters incorrectly. Could someone please tell me what can I do to fix this dilemma?

### Lights

---

Plane:

[image]

Circle:

[image]

Sphere (specifically,hemi):

[image]

### Node Setup

---

[image]

Comment: You hide a circle inside the sphere. The sphere does not shine into the scene, but is only visible to the camera. The circle is not visible to camera, but shines light into the scene. Second approach is to modify normals of the sphere with a custom normal data so that all of them point down in single direction, like on a plane.

Comment: No,I actually rendered the meshes separately. The sphere is all by itself.

Comment: I know, I am not describing your setup, I am proposing a new one. One where there is circle inside sphere, or a sphere all by itself but with changed normals.

Comment: Oh,sorry. I have a tendency of seeing things in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a little advice from my commentor,Jaroslav Jerryno Novotny,I figured it out. For the first Mapping node connected to the Geometry Normal socket,change the Z-axis scale from 1.000 to 0.000. I know you're facepalming right now because this question was stupid and it had an easy answer,but c'est la vie.

### Solution

---

[image]